# How to implement Toll-Free Bridging in ObjectiveC/C?

Tags: objective-c

The iOS and OS X Sdk have a very cool concept of toll-free bridging. If I were to write my own  code in C and write Obj-C wrapper for it, and want to use it as Toll-Free-Bridged, how should I do that? Any examples please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the tutorial at https://web.archive.org/web/20111013023821/http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToCreateTollFreeBridgedClass. Basically, you need to create a C structure, that has the same size and layout as the obj-c counterpart. Also some funky stuff has to be done to correctly implement retain/release.

Comment: cocoadev.com seems to be no more, got any updated link?

Comment: web archive version: https://web.archive.org/web/20111013023821/http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToCreateTollFreeBridgedClass

Comment: This has been flagged for removal because it doesn't include the necessary details to solve the problem in the answer itself. Could you please edit this answer so users don't need to follow the link (or web archive version of the link) to understand how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this, if you can, is to write your code in Objective-C, and then wrap it in C. That avoids all of the tricky parts of toll-free bridging (and those tricky parts are only getting trickier. -retain/-release is more complicated if you want to support ARC __weak for example).

Comment: But wouldn't that kill the purpose? I would want to implement the core in C so that it can be reusable out of ObjC environment (and also to gain some performance boost, if any).

Comment: That's the "if you can" part. If you really need to wrap C, you have to do it the hard way.